# How to use 1 bit binary arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, binary, compression

Javascript supports reading and writing to binary arrays with the [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) interface.

Essentially it creates a memory buffer of binary data, and then reads that binary data through a "view". This view tells the browser how many bits of data should be read at a time and makes an array out of it..

For example the bits 0000000100000001 would look like this through different views:

```
// 8 bit (char) array
charArray[0] = 1;
charArray[1] = 1;

// 16 bit (short int) array
intArray[0] = 257;
```

For a project I am working on I need to store only 1 bit of data at a time, and file-size is a concern. The smallest built in array size Javascript has is a char array, and using a char array to just save either 1 or 0 would be a waste of space because it has to store all the leading 0's.

**My Question:** What would be the fastest way in terms of performance to read binary data 1 bit at a time in Javascript?

I know javascript supports [bitwise operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp), but I can't find anything about their performance. The only other thing I can think of would be to use a char array, and write custom logic that would subtract the proper number to read only one bit at a time.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do with the bits? Performance wise, you should care about using bitwise operations roughly as much as you care about `+`.

Comment: @ASDFGerte The bits are used to create the structure of a custom tree. It's basically a binary tree mixed with a quad tree depending on the level of branching.  Do you have any idea how much of a performance hit I would run into? I guess it would be 1 addition operation per memory lookup right?

Comment: The logic for what to do with that bit is likely to take a lot more than actually retrieving the bit. That's why imho it's much more interesting whether the steps afterwards can be combined and possibly optimized than how to read the bit. I don't know specifics on how interpretation/jit handles these operations, but bitwise operations are easier than addition from a processor point of view. Due to fixed clock ticks etc it's likely they will take approximately the same time though, unless some extra optimization i don't know about makes bitwise operations faster again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, bitwise operations in almost all languages are extremely fast.

If you read and store 8 bits at a time (which is usually the smallest size languages provide for) you should have no trouble meeting your time requirements.

Extracting the i*th* bit in an 8 bit value is fast if you implement it as a rightshift and a bitwise and (or a leftshift and a rightshift).